# DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() with CultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, cultureinfo

I have the code:

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()
```

That give's me the english day of the week name, I want to have the german version, how to add CultureInfo here to get the german day of the week name?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
var day = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `DateTimeFormat.DayNames` property of the german `CultureInfo`.
For example:

```
CultureInfo german = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
string sunday = german.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int)DayOfWeek.Sunday];
```

Answer (score 6):

[`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) is an enumeration, so the `ToString` method on it is not culture sensitive.

You will need to write a function to convert the Enum value to a corresponding string in German, if you insist on using `DayOfWeek`:

```
string DayOfWeekGerman(DayOfWeek dow)
{

    switch(dow)
    {
      case(DayOfWeek.Sunday)
         return "German Sunday";
      case(DayOfWeek.Monday)
         return "German Monday";
      ...
    }
}
```

A better approach is to use `ToString` from `DateTime` directly:

```
CultureInfo german = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
string dayName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", german);
```

Comment: The article mentions `DateTime.ToString(String)` or the `DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` for the localized name - there's no need to write out a function for it.

Answer (score 6):

This is the solution in Visual Basic

```
Dim GermanCultureInfo As Globalization.CultureInfo = New Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")

Return GermanCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

The function of the solution is Obsolete by the way
`DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"))`

Answer (score 3):

I like this one:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static string GetDayOfWeek(this DateTime uiDateTime, CultureInfo culture = null)
    {
        if (culture == null)
        {
            culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        }

        return culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(uiDateTime.DayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

And according to your question:

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
var day = uiDateTime.GetDayOfWeek(culture);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

string day = date.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("es-MX"));

Console.WriteLine(day); //Jueves
```

only change "es-MX" for the region you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to return your day name as same language

```
CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("ar-EG");   
MessageBox.Show(myCI.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DayOfWeek.Friday));
```

[image]
note: `DateTime` returns a `DayOfWeek` Enumeration so I use the code to return from
another Enumeration