# Where to put "new CultureInfo("nl-NL")" if DayOfWeek is already declared?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, dayofweek

**Where do I put the new CultureInfo("nl-NL")?**
The user needs to give a date. 
The programe needs to show the day in Dutch.

```
DateTime date;

System.Console.Write("give date (DD/MM/JJJJ) : ");
date = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

System.Console.Write("the day is a  " + date.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString() with CultureInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716762/datetime-now-dayofweek-tostring-with-cultureinfo)

Comment: @EugenePodskal 
I have seen it, and its different.

Comment: In such a case you should be more specific about what does `Where do I put the new CultureInfo("nl-NL")?` mean. Your question should at least describe the result you strive to achieve. Otherwise we are just left with trying to guess what you actually want, and that doesn't usually end well. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EugenePodskal Is this better?

Comment: Yes, it is better. And, using the answer from proposed duplicate, I get `zaterdag` as a result. So I am not sure how this question is different from that one.

Comment: Becouse the user need to give a date in console and not use Today.

Comment: Ehhm, and what prevents you from substituting `DateTime.Now` with the parsed `date` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it directly. CultureInfo implements the IFormatProvider interface.

```
DateTime date;

var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");

System.Console.Write("give date (DD/MM/JJJJ) : ");
date = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine(),cultureInfo);



System.Console.Write("the day is a  " + cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(date.DayOfWeek));
```

Comment: got the following error
    "The type or namespace name 'CultureInfo' could not be found   (are    you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: using System.Globalization;

Comment: using System.Globalization;
The error is gone, but it is still in english.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: The user gives a date.
The programme than gives what day it is in Dutch

Comment: Use: cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(date.DayOfWeek)

Comment: the cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(date.DayOfWeek) did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var newCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL");
var dayOfWeek = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);

System.Console.WriteLine("the day is a " + dayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this with the other using statements:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
```

Put this as the first line of code in your `Main` method:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
        new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
Console.WriteLine("Weekday: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat
   .GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek));
```

Then your application will use that culture. It will be used for datetime formatting, number formatting etc.

If you were using a UI application, like windows forms, you would also need to set the ui culture like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
     new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
```

When you set the `CurrentUICulture` then the application will get information from your resources file for displaying labels etc in the UI.

Comment: Got the following error: "The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: You need to put the using statement at the very top where the other using statements are. See my edit.